# If mongodb aggregate does not use indexes for $lookup why does my performance increase when using indexes?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following code snippet to run the aggregation command.

```
      console.time("something");
      const cursor = await db.collection("main").aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            mainField: mainField,
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "reference",
            localField: "referenceId",
            foreignField: "referenceField",
            as: "something",
          },
        },
      ]);
      const results = await cursor.toArray();
      console.timeEnd("something");
```

I have a cheap cloud server for testing purposes (2gb ram, 1 cpu etc.) where mongodb is stored.

I insert 10k documents into main and reference collections (so combined 20k documents inserted).

Without using indexes and running the above aggregation query it takes more than 30 seconds to return the result.

If I have the following index on the reference collection and run the above aggregation query the results take around 1.2 seconds.

```
await db.collection("reference").createIndex({ referenceField: 1 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the MongoDB manual doesn't currently mention potential index usage for `$lookup`, but this is definitely the case.

A simple `$lookup` query similar to your example performs an equality match on the `foreignField` in another collection, so you've added the correct index to improve performance (assuming this field also is reasonably selective).

As at MongoDB 4.0 the index usage for `$lookup` is not reported in [aggregation explain output](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation). There is a relevant issue to watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue tracker: [SERVER-22622: Improve $lookup explain to indicate query plan on the "from" collection](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22622).

Comment: I created a documentation suggestion ([DOCS-10681](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10681)) to mention index usage as at MongoDB 3.4, but it has languished in the backlog. MongoDB 3.6 added [more expressive `$lookup` features](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries), so the possible explain options are much broader now. However, the potential for index usage should at least be mentioned in the manual so I will submit a PR to improve this.